# Jquery onclick get href value and add to browse window path

Tags: jquery

Below HTML & JS logic...

On clicking `li` tab, If `li` id & `div class="content"` id matches.. filter `div` content and display. this works fine.

Now requirement is.. On clicking `li` tab, above filter have to be happen.. also it has to get `li` `a` -- `href` value and add to browser window url path like "http://www.example.com/test1.html#!id1" when "ele1" is clicked.

When some one copy this url "http://www.example.com/test1.html#!id1" and paste in browser window. It have to load with filtered content based on ID value.

Thanks in advance for help!! Sorry to trouble you ppl!!

**HTML:**

**test1.html**

```
<ul>
 <li class="slist selected" id="ele1"><a href="#!id1">Element 1</a></li>
 <li class="slist" id="ele2"><a href="#!id2">Element 2</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="cwrapper">
 <div class="contentEle">
  <div class="content ele1">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...
  </div>
  <div class="content ele2">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var $sListEle = $('.slist').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $ele = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(800);
    $('.cwrapper .contentEle > div.content').not($ele).hide();
    $sListEle.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});

var $els = $('.contentEle div.content').hide(),
    $curr = $();

$('.slist').on('click', function () {
    $('.slist.selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $curr = $els.filter('.' + this.id).hide();
    $curr.slice(0, 3).show();
    $els.not($curr).hide();
}).filter('.selected').click();
```

Comment: to get the hash or the url you can use `window.location.hash`, to get the element from your link click, you can use `$($(this).attr('href'))`

Comment: Hi Pete.. Thanks for your comment.. Not sure how to get id value of clicked element and display on browser window with the url... # tag will display by default. But, on clicking here.. we are doing 2 functions.. 1 for ajax loader..another for to load page with hash tag.